# Cucumber scenario searching in a file using ruby

Tags: file-io, cucumber

I have a cucumber scenario which checks for certain strings in a file. Not a very ideal way of doing things but it has been deemed an absolute need.

**My Cucumber scenario which has a table:**

And the email should have

```
|search_string|
|Nokogiri     |
|Cucumber     |
|White Tiger  |
```

**My Step definition**

```
Given /^the email should have$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    check_email(hash["search_string"])
  end
end
```

**My check_email method**

```
require 'nokogiri'

def check_email(search_string)
  htmlFile = File.open(filename).read
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(htmlFile)
  if (doc.content["#{search_string}"])
    puts true
    return true
  end
  htmlFile.close
  puts false
  return false
end
```

The file I am reading although is ".txt" file extension the contents in the file are in HTML format.

1. The method is reading the correct file
2. The file has the contents that the method is trying to locate

Now to the actual problem that I am seeing.

1. The search_string in my cucumber scenario has 3 values to be searched.  "White Tiger" is not there in the file
2. Since "White Tiger" is not in the file the test should fail, but instead the test passes / I should say I see "green" and when I output the actual results as above in the code it clearly shows (true for Nokogiri, true for Cucumber and false for White Tiger).

My question is so how can I do this. Cucumber table results should show GREEN/PASS only for values that are available in the file and RED/FAIL for values not in the file.

Can someone please help me with this. Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber won't fail a step unless an exception is raised (this is what happens when an RSpec matcher is not satisfied).  Simply returning true or false is meaningless.

Your assertion should probably look something like

```
if (!doc.content["#{search_string}"])
    raise "Expected the file to contain '#{search_string}'"
end
```

Comment: If my or undees answer helped you out, consider up-voting and marking one of them as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `check_email` function as is, you can add an assertion to your step definition:

```
Given /^the email should have$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    check_email(hash["search_string"]).should be_true
  end
end
```

You could also just make your e-mail function return a string, and check its contents in your step definition:

```
require 'nokogiri'

def email_contents
  html = IO.read(filename)
  doc  = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
  return doc.content
end

# ...

Given /^the email should have$/ do |table|
  contents = email_contents

  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    contents.should include(hash["search_string"])
  end
end
```

These aren't better or worse than Jon M's approach--just another alternative.